# How do I overcome the script tag error with the Twitter widget?

Tags: managed-package

My internal client is building a landing page for a Salesforce user community, in Salesforce. The error message returned is, 'The script tag isn't allowed' when the code is inserted into the HTML. I reviewed a doc in re: Lightning Components and an external source but didn't comprehend the paragraph following:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.resourceName}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

Perhaps THAT should have been my question. My apologies.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/PebbleGo" data-widget-id="887761656415125504">#PebbleGo Tweets</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: a little context and maybe the error message? what have you tried to overcome this issue? where are you using this? is this the twitter widget from SDO orgs? Please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Thanks, and welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Okay...I did take the tour and thought I was asking a direct question, but apparently not.

My internal client is building a landing page for a Salesforce user community, in Salesforce.

The error message returned is, 'The script tag isn't allowed' when the code is inserted into the HTML.

I reviewed a doc in re: lightening components and an external source but didn't comprehend the paragraph following:

<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.resourceName}"
afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />

Perhaps THAT should have been my question. My apologies.

Comment: How do I determine what is 'Resource.resourceName' is?

Comment: [lightning require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm)

Comment: Thank you, glls!

If I am understanding properly, the resource name is a JavaScript library, with the actual library resource concatenated.

In my case, the resource is likely a JavaScript folder containing the actual .js file.

The expression would then be, {!$Resource.js + '/filename.js'}

Correct?